# iOS: UIAlertView with multiline UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitextview, uialertview

I'm looking for a way to add a multiline `UITextView` to an `UIAlertView`. I googled a lot, but I couldn't find a working solution.

I'm using iOS 5.

Or is that only possible with a subclass of `UIAlertView`?

EDIT: I need a multiple-line input.

Comment: According to the `UIAlertView`official documentation, you should **NOT** subclass `UIAlertView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing `UIAlertViews` is flagged as bad practice by apple. So its probably best to create your own custom `UIViewController` which looks like an alert view.

Make it so that instead of your function calling an alert, it loads your new View controller

This is a good example of an animation for your `UIViewController` to make it act like a typical IOS `AlertView`

```
  -(void)initialDelayEnded {
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.001, 0.001);
self.view.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:kTransitionDuration/1.5 animations:^{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.1, 1.1);
}completion:^(BOOL complete){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:kTransitionDuration/2 animations:^{
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.9, 0.9);
    }completion:^(BOOL complete){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:kTransitionDuration/2 animations:^{
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        }];
    }];
}];
```

}